# sshd throws invalid password after date change

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, busybox

**Problem**

I am working on an embedded device, while developing code it is really nice to have a ssh connection. The device is portable and sometimes completely disconnected from battery thus to keep the current time on the board, on startup I update the date and time from my remote server. The problem is that sshd server on the device, after running `date` command, does not accept form of connecting, replying with `Permission denied, please try again.` message.

**What's going on**

1. I **can** start a device, connect to the network, start sshd and use ssh
2. I **can't** start a device, connect to the network, update time, start sshd and use ssh
3. I **can't** start a device, connect to the network, start sshd, update time and use ssh
4. I **can** start the device, connect to the network, update time, restart device, connect to the network again, start sshd and use ssh

**What I've found**

After digging into it for a while I've found that `sshd` server logs this:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
Account root has expired
input_userauth_request: invalid user root
```

even before I get asked for a password. It isn't there if the time wasn't updated. The problem seems to be that after system time is changed the `/etc/shadow` file will somehow lock root user.

**What I've tried**

I tried running `ssh` in debug mode on my pc (from which I am trying to connect to embedded device), I ran `sshd` in debug mode and I tried to update time with `rdate` command and I did it so many times that me typing wrong password is not possible (since I have no problems connecting when I do nothing about the time), I also tried connecting with ssh keys instead of password. I tried running `passwd -u root` command but it didn't change anything.

**What I am using**

```
# busybox
BusyBox v1.18.3 (2016-03-20 23:15:14 CET) multi-call binary.
# /usr/sbin/sshd -v
sshd: illegal option -- v
OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
```

Comment: The error mesage `Account root has expired` seems rather clear. Does your sytem have `chage`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If that matters, the `etc/shadow` file looks exactly the same before and after updating the time

Comment: There is not reason why it should change if you update the time. If the account is set to expire on some time (which you can check with `chage -l root`) and that time is after today you should be able to log in and work. If you correct the date (going into the future and past expiry date) then no change will happen to /etc/shadow. But the data comparision will show expired because system time changed. Not shadow.

Comment: It there a way to check it without `chage`? Also, changing the password with `passwd` command doesn't seem to do anything to the expiry days listed there for `root` user..

Comment: Embedded. Busybox. Arg, lack of normal commands. You might only have [these](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) and neither of those commands seem to help. Any change to test with `apt-get install chage` or whatever package manager (if any) is in use.  (My normal idea would be to just compile the command, but you are probably crosscompiling for the embedded installation and things get much more interesting that way.

Comment: Two more questions: 1) Do you have the image which is flashed to the embedded device? Can you mount its filesystems using loopback from another linux system (a full install, not a minimal install with busybox) From there you could `chroot` and `chage -l`. 2) Does logging in with other users work fine. You only mentioned root, but I assume that you only used that for emergencies and that you get similar problems with other accounts or when su-ing to uid0.

Comment: I have just been informed over sshd_config? Can you add the one from the embedded device to your post. Esp. if it uses PAM. Apparently if you use password ageing and "usePAM no" your password never goes INACTIVE and ssh keys work without password expiration warnings.  Source: http://www.unix.com/linux/256596-linux-password-aging-ssh-keys.html (thanks Dave for pointing me at that).

Comment: Team work, that's what we do here.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! 1) First of all I have a serial port which gives me access to the root console 2) I dont use any packet manager, everything is cross-compiled.. 3) `UsePAM no` is default and setting it to `yes` gives `Unsupported option UsePAM` error 4) the only solution I have found so far is editing the `/etc/shadow/` file (while I know I shouldn't be doing it) and changing it from `root:$1$(secret):17049:5:99999:7:5:2000:` to `root:$1$(secret):17049:0:::::` 5) also I got to the core of a problem - expired root account so most of my initial question is obsolete - should I rewrite it?

Comment: Large rewrites after it has answers are somewhat frowned upon, but this question has no answers yet. So go ahead.